# Delete whole row if there is duplication in column B

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem with "whole row deletion" if there is duplication in one Column. I would like to delete whole row, if there is duplication in column B.

My Table has A,B,C,D columns. If i mark column B and i  use  delete duplicity - it will delete just duplicity from column B. How to get rid of the whole row if there is duplication in column B?

Any suggestions?

Thanks indeed

```
Example:
        A               B             C           D
    car.name        car.color      car.price   250 000
    car.value       car.color      car.speed    250 km/h
```

in this example i would like to delete 2nd row (duplicity in column B)- i have more than 10 k rows, but according to me, principle will be same

Comment: It would help a lot if you could include a snapshot of a sample of your data (i.e. column A, and B) then include a snapshot of the desired output

Comment: If you *select* columns A, B, C & D then choose Data ► Data Tools ► Remove Duplicates, you should be able to **Unselect All** then check Column B (optionally choose *My data has headers*). Click `OK` in the lower right and you should get the results you are looking for.

Comment: @Jeeped - thank you, it works, please, write it as an answer in order to accept your advice

Comment: Since your question was actually tagged with `excel-vba`, it's probably better to stay on topic and accept Liniel's answer below. It is the abbreviated version of what you would receive if you macro-recorded the actions I described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$6").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2), Header:=xlNo
```

Something like that?
That will delete row with duplicates from second column form range A1:D6.

Comment: That looks right but I probably would have gone with full column references given the OP's actual data set (>10K rows). `.Range("$A:$D")` wouldn't have made any difference and would have left the VBA command more versatile for future use.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is straight forward.

Excel already has a built in function to Remove Duplicate rows.

Once you click the button, you just need to tell Excell to check duplicates in which column

Here is what to do in VBA:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlNo
```

And here is the manual task:

[image]